# How to code a JFrame in Netbeans instead of drag and drop?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have to work on a school project at home so I copied my `JFrame` files onto a USB and I usually just copy and paste the code onto a new class, but since we are working on GUI, I just have the source code plus the form code. I have no idea where to copy and paste the form code, and I do not want to attempt to replicate the same drag and drop that I have already done.

I realize this may be a stupid easy question but I can't seem to find out anywhere

Comment: Maybe start by getting rid of the form designer and make you UIs through pure code - [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) might be a good start

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new project.
- Do not create any main class of it.
- Now, create a new package in your project, name it anything.
- Go to your project working directory (If you are on NetBeans, default working directory is

> "C:\Users\PeterParker\Documents\NetBeansProjects"
>
> or
>
> "C:\Users\PeterParker\Documents\NetBeansProjects40"

).

- Open your project folder which you have recently created.
- Now, open 'src' folder, it will have folder with the name you used to create the package in your project, open that folder.
- Paste here your source code plus the form code files, NetBeans will detect them and your files will be added as they were earlier in not less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Why not copy the entire project at school and add to your Netbeans Projects folder at home?